# Creating new rows from columns using FME

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, fme-transformer

I am trying to convert columns to new features by using FME 2020.
I have tried Attribute splitter than feature joiner but until now without any great success.

The image below explains what I need.

Any tip ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd make a copy of the features, delete Col3 & Col4 from the first, and from the 2nd set delete cols 1 & 2, then rename 3 & 4 to 1 & 2:

[image: workbench screenshot]

Comment: Dan - great minds thinking alike!

Answer (score 4):

If it's that simple, I would just make two connections out of the same output port. Each goes to an AttributeManager transformer.

On one AttributeManager you delete Col3 and Col4. On the other, you delete Col1 and Col2; and rename Col3 to Col1 and Col4 to Col2.

Then just join those outputs back together. Now you'll have 6 features, with the attributes in the What I Want table.